# Required fields under Record Types and Subcategory type

Tags: formula, picklist, validation-rule, required-field

I need to make those fields required under 2 conditions. Record type and Subcategory (picklist).

I stated doing Validation rules, for the first one:
Record type: Passport
Subcategory: Renewal and New Issue
Field required: Request Received from Location

```
RecordType.Id = "012U0000000a3kVIAQ"
&&
(
ISPICK ( Subcategory__c , "Renewal")  || 
ISPICK ( Subcategory__c , "New Issue") )
&&
ISBLANK ( Request_Received_from_Location__c)
```

**I get a syntax error: Error: Field Subcategory__c is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions.**

[image: REquirements]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no `IsPICk` formula in sales force , it should be `ISPICKVAL` i would recommend go through [Pick list formula](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/advanced_formulas/picklist_formulas) trailhead module.

don't use Recordtype id because it could be different in other Environments(QA/UAT/Prod) Boxes, i would recommend to use `$RecordType.Name = "Passport"`

Comment: I fixed it. Thank you very much . I am new to this, but I am learning !